# I need to put each element one under the other, even if it fits next

Tags: css, vue.js

Like the title say, i need to put one element under the other like a chat app. When the message its large it works fine, but when the text fits next to the other it put it there. I need a way to do this, i will attach an image.

```
<div class="other_message" v-for="item in messages" :key="item.data" v-if=" -- some condition --">
    {{ item.data }}
</div>
<div class="my_message" v-else>
    {{ item.data }}
[enter image description here][1]</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.other_message {
    max-width: 60%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.my_message {
    max-width: 60%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #448AFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add "clear:both;" to the elements. This clears or ignores the floats above said element. More information about the "clear" property can be found here: [MDN - Clear CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

```css
.other_message {
    max-width: 60%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both; /* add this */
}

.my_message {
    max-width: 60%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #448AFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both; /* add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="other_message" v-for="item in messages" :key="item.data" v-if=" -- some condition --">
    {{ item.data }}
</div>
<div class="my_message" v-else>
    {{ item.data }}
[enter image description here][1]</div>
```

Comment: thank you, sometimes when you search in google for a solution to a simple problem you could not find anything. Your answer was simple and perfect.

Again... thank you, you saved my life